# Which channel configuration is supported

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell 720xd server and a lot of these DIMMs on the shelf and would like to insert as many as possible into the server:

```
sk hynix 8GB 1Rx4 PC3L-12800R-11-12-C2 
HMT41GR7AFR4A-PB T8 AH 1347C
```

From what I [found out](https://www.skhynix.com/products.view.do?vseq=1023&cseq=75) these are their specs:

- Power Supply: VDD=1.35V (1.283V to 1.45V)
- VDDQ = 1.35V (1.283V to 1.45V)
- VDDSPD=3.0V to 3.6V
- Backward Compatible with 1.5V DDR3 Memory Module
- 8 internal banks
- Data transfer rates: PC3-14900, PC3-12800, PC3-10600, PC3-8500
- Bi-Directional Differential Data Strobe
- 8 bit pre-fetch
- Burst Length (BL) switch on-the-fly BL8 or BC4(Burst Chop)
- Supports ECC error correction and detection

According to the server manual these types of DIMMs are supported:

> Your system supports DDR3 unbuffered ECC DIMMs (ECC UDIMMs),
>   registered DIMMs (RDIMMs), and load reduced DIMMs (LRDIMMs). It
>   supports DDR3 and DDR3L voltage specifications.
>   The system contains 24 memory sockets split into two sets of 12 sockets, 
>   one set per processor. Each 12-socket set is organized into four channels.

Further information:

```
Memory bus operating frequency can be 1866 MT/s, 1600 MT/s, 1333 MT/s, 1066 MT/s, or 800 MT/s depending on:
• DIMM type (UDIMM, RDIMM, or LRDIMM)
• DIMM configuration (number of ranks)
• maximum frequency of the DIMMs
• number of DIMMs populated per channel
• DIMM operating voltage
• system profile selected (for example, Performance Optimized, Custom, or Dense Configuration Optimized)
• maximum supported DIMM frequency of the processors
```

This table in the [server manual](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r720_owners-manual_en-us.pdf) (see pages 40 onwards) makes me hope that I could insert 16 or even 24 of those modules, but I am not sure:

[image]

The [technical guide](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1028226424.pdf) states this on page 23:
[image]
[image]

As my knowledge on RDIMMS and the technologies involved is very limited and I don't want to go for "trial and error": is it possible to insert 24 of the mentioned DIMMs or not ?

Comment: I strongly suggest contacting Dell's support department with this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the vendor support is the only source of information you can trust.

Comment: @JennyD Thanks for your input. While it is true that Dell should be able to tell me this but someone with the proper technical knowledge about RDIMMS, ranks, frequencies etc should be able to "decipher" this. Therefore I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a long story short: it is possible to add 24 of the mentioned 8 GB DIMMs to the mentioned server.

Might be of interest for those that happen to get a bunch of Google GSA T4s ;-)